# Basic IF/THEN Ampscript question

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a data extension attribute called MemberTier and the value can be one of 3 possibilities, S,G,P, or Silver, Gold, Platinum.

I want to take the abbreviation and translate that into the full name in the body of the email but I'm stuck.  I've looked on other forums and I feel like this is right but I'm getting a ton of validation errors. Here's what I have:

```
%%[
set @MemberTier = MemberTier

IF @MemberTier == "S" THEN
 set @Tier = "Silver"
ELSEIF  @MemberTier == "G" THEN
 set @Tier = "Gold"
ELSEIF  @MemberTier == "P" THEN
 set @Tier = "Platinum"
ENDIF
]%%

%%=v(@Tier)=%%
```

Comment: what are your validation errors, they may not be related to this code

Comment: you're right, the validation errors had nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 2):

I'll guess and say your send context doesn't include `MemberTier`.

I'm on team "no naked personalization strings" (aka don't assume your send context variables exist, check them with [**AttributeValue**](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue)):

```ampscript
%%[

set @debug = 1
set @MemberTier = AttributeValue("MemberTier")

if @debug == 1 then
  output(concat("<br>memberTier: ", @memberTier))
endif

if empty(@MemberTier) then 

  set @Tier = "Unknown"

  IF @MemberTier == "S" THEN
   set @Tier = "Silver"
  ELSEIF @MemberTier == "G" THEN
   set @Tier = "Gold"
  ELSEIF @MemberTier == "P" THEN
   set @Tier = "Platinum"
  ENDIF

else
  raiseError("MemberTier doesn't exist or is empty", 1)
endif

]%%
%%=v(@Tier)=%%
```

Also, I'd suggest adding a default value for `Tier` since you have no catch-all   else in your conditional.

Comment: the MemberTier is an attribute in the data extension I'm sending to, and a member will only be a S, G or P Tier.

Comment: I'm also wondering, my %%=v(@Tier)=%% variable is nested within another personalization string and I know that's not always ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  the %%=v(@Tier)=%% was in a pre-existing personalization string so once I edited the variable to simply @Tier, it worked as expected.  thanks!